# Connect NXP i.MX7D to Android Things Toolkit app

Tags: android, android-things, android-things-console

I have the NXP i.MX7D Android Things development kit. The kit is set up and connecting to my wifi without issue, but I'm having trouble connecting the device to the [Android Things Toolkit app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.things.companion&hl=en_US) on my Pixel.

The issue:
When I open the phone app, I see a screen that says "You haven't set up any devices yet". When I select the button to "Set up nearby device", I am taken to a screen that says " Your device will display a 4-digit code when you start setting it up." My kit never shows a code and the app won't allow me to advance without entering the code.

I verified that the latest version of Android Things is installed on the kit and the latest app version is installed on my phone. I made sure that the kit and my phone are connected to the same wifi network.

What I've tried:

- Doing a factory reset on the kit
- Installing the kit software using the command line tool rather than the UI method
- Disconnecting and reconnecting to wifi (on both phone and kit)
- Installing the phone app first and then doing a factory reset on the kit
- Install the kit software first and then installing the phone app
- Connecting with the kit via bluetooth and then trying the app set up

Luckily, I don't *need* the phone app to develop and install apps on the kit, but it sure would be nice to have. If anyone one has any guidance on connecting the toolkit app to the kit, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: what is shown on the screen of your kit at the point of pairing? If its just black you might look at reseating the wire/connector

Comment: I had a similar problem. I tried that nearby setup and I saw a very strange pairing ID which I assumed was the board, but since I use it over USB I did not worried about it and skipped the BT step

Comment: @Blundell, thanks for your comment. The kit displays its usual landing screen whether the phone app is trying to pair or not. I checked all of the kit UI settings to see if there was a brute force way to get it to give me a pairing code to punch into the phone, but no luck.

Comment: @shalafi, I know what you mean with the weird bluetooth code - I saw the same thing. I tried both with the device paired and not paired, but I still couldn't get the kit to give me the 4 digit access code that the Android Things Toolkit app is asking for. So have you tried pairing the kit to the Android Things Toolkit app? If so, was it successful? I still just get the "You haven't set up any devices yet" screen when I open the app.

Comment: I did configure WiFi and that screen went away so I didn't try again.

Answer (score 4):

When you first boot the Android Things developer kit (or reboot after a factory reset), you should see the following screen:

[image: Start Screen]

*If you do not see this screen, you do not have the correct image installed on the board. Use the [hardware setup instructions](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d) to flash the default image.*

Tapping **GET STARTED** will display the setup screen. This screen contains the 4-digit code you need to pair the device to the companion app (highlighted in red):

[image: Setup Screen]

*If you tap **SKIP**, there is not currently a way to get back to display the pairing code without doing a factory reset or flashing the image again.*

Enter the code into the Toolkit companion app to pair the device.

Comment: THANK YOU, @devunwired ! That was exactly what I needed. Now that you point it out, I see it, but, wow, there are so many easy UI tweaks that would make that code more discoverable. Thanks a ton for pointing it out to me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, we've actually just pushed a new version that makes the code easier to see based on similar statements from others.

Comment: Hooray! Thanks so much for your assistance and responsiveness.